# Overlay two plots *after* I have made plt.show() in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am familiar with the idea of putting several plots in an overlay by calling the plot function several times

```
plt.plot(f1)
plt.plot(f2)
plt.plot(f2)
plt.show()
```

But what if I want to plot data that I have already put on a canvas?

i was thinking to use the `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` object returned by each plt.plot. If I store them in suitable variables then I can reuse them at a later time. But how do I get a plot out of these `matplotlib.lines.Line2D`? Maybe I am trying  a doomed strategy

```
p3000=plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

and then

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_line(p3000[0])
```

but I get `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure`

I have also tried `get_xydata` member but ti does not give the points in a form I am able to read.

Comment: Because you cannot have one line in two figures you would need to call `plt.plot(..)` again for the new figure.

Comment: This sounds as a useless constraint to me. At any rate, can I get back my x and y data and replot them on my own?

Comment: This not useless; it ensures the correct transforms being set at any time. `x,y = line.get_data()` might be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks a lot this gives back the data, and also the method `get_xydata` I had tried before, but for some reason was not working then.